# Drupal cron job and re-index site problem

Tags: drupal, cron, reindex

I have a problem in my drupal site. When I run the cron.php multiple times, the index result got stuck at 99%. And the new contents won't show up in search results. What can I do to fix this?

I have tried setting max_allowed_packet to 24M and mysqli.reconnect = On

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to lower the number of items to index per run? I had the same issue till I did that.

Goto the Search Settings page and change the number of items to index per cron run to 10. Then run cron and see what you get. You may have to run a few times to catch up, but then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the PHP filter in some of your nodes and used a [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6) this can cause a problem with indexing.  As seen here: [Cron cannot run on Drupal: the drupal_goto() case](http://chirale.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/cron-cannot-run-on-drupal-the-drupal_goto-case/).  There is a thread on http://drupal.org about this as well: [cron breaks on drupal_goto](http://drupal.org/node/102138)